# How to persist a sorting option in a RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Hi I have a RadGrid in my asp.net application and basically I am being asked to persist the sorting clicked on the header name throught out the user session so basically lets say I have the RadGrid with the following headings.

```
ID Name  OrderNumber Shipped
```

So by default it is sorted in ASC order by name when you first arrive at the page, but now.. if the User resorts it by clicking on the Name heading again it will make it in DESC order. So what I am being asked to do is to make the web remember the sorting option no matter if the user navigates to a different page within the application.  So when the user comes back he should see the gridview in the order he/she picked before leaving to another page within the appliacation.

How can I do this with a RadGrid, without using `HttpCookie` ?

I do not think I should show my code as it is the plain default set up of a RadGrid BUT if necessary I will just grab something and put it here, I am just not sure the best way to go about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a feature that we should be looking from a third party control, rather than an implementation item when using it in a project.

So if the requirement is only to persist within the user session, HttpCookie or even ASP.Net session would work.  But if the requirement is to maintain even across same users next log-ins, even database would be a go od option rather than putting the weight on the ASP.Net session or Cookie transferring client to server every time.

Comment: Along with this answer, for help with extracting all of the required information (sorting order, filtering etc.) needed from the RadGrid this article is great to reference: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-saving-settings-on-per-user-basis.html